# Relation 1 to N in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm a new python developer. Now I'm learning Django and I'm having some troubles.

In Java for example, I can have an 1 to N relation, like this:

```
public class Son(){ 
   // some things
}

public class Father(){ 
   Son son[]; 
   // some things
}
```

But, if I need to model it in Django, how i can do that?

I tried the code bellow, but it provides only 1 to 1 relation:

```
class Father: 
    father = models.ForeignKey('Son')
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Son: 
    father = models.ForeignKey(Father)
```

this way any Son can have only one father... however any father can have many son's, this is a many to one relationship

you can make it better still

```
class Son:
    father_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('father.id'))
    father = relationship("Father", backref="sons")
```

this will now provide Father instances with a reference named sons that has many sons in a list(not sure why you chose father/son as opposed to parent/child but meh)

Comment: His question is about Django, not SQLAlchemy. `models.ForeignKey(Father)` implicitly creates both the backwards relationship on `Father` and the `father_id` column on `Son`, your second example is not valid in Django.

Answer (score -1):

That's the best way to do (always define related_name):

```
class Son(models.Model): 
    father = models.ForeignKey(Father, related_name="sons")
```

Then you can do:

```
dad = Father.objects.get(id=5)
for son in dad.sons.all():
     print son.name
```

Comment: There is usually no need to define related_name, since the default is fine.

Comment: Well it's not needed but it's better. "sons" is shorter and clearer  than "son_set".